# No resource found that matches the given name Styles.xml

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, styles

I am trying to design a new theme for my android application in C# in Xamarin. 
I have followed a few tutorials and answers on this but I keep getting the error

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@android:style/Theme.CustomActionBarTheme')

I have check a few of the relevant answer for this error but none seem to work for me :(

Heres my xml code which is located in my Values folder under Resources:
**Styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<resources>
  <style 
    name="AppBaseTheme" 
    parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
  </style>

  <style 
    name="CustomActionBarTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item 
      name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar
    </item>
  </style>

  <style 
    name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item 
      name="android:background">#033C73
    </item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Can anyone help me out a bit?

Thanks

- EDIT *
  So here is the top of my MainActivity.cs

  ```
  [Activity(Label = "My App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.CustomerActionBarTheme")]
  public class MainActivity : Activity
  {
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
      {
          base.OnCreate(bundle);

          // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
      }
  ```

Comment: please add the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make changes in your manifest file

```
<application

android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

 </application>
```

Now you must be declaring it as

```
android:theme="@android:style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

Comment: So in my MainActivity.cs I have `[Activity(Label = "My App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/CustomerActionBarTheme")]` Im still getting an error. I must be doing something wrong somewhere...

Comment: yes.  Error is with your theme declaration. Correct Spelling. Also try  to remove @android. Declare it as android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

Comment: I have it working now. Thank you so much!! I had to remove the @android and fix my silly spelling error.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your theme Theme.CustomActionBarTheme ? You call it but it doesn't exist

Comment: How do I go about making one or adding it in? Im pretty new to this.

Comment: As you can seen in your resources file, there are 3 named themes "AppBaseTheme", "CustomActionBarTheme" and "MyActionBar". You can create new ones by following same structure and name it with the name="" property

Comment: Sorry for this but as you said, CustomActionBarTheme is a theme so shouldnt I be able to use that theme for my application without getting an error?

Comment: Yes but you seem to call "Theme.CustomActionBarTheme" in your code, whereas it should be "CustomActionBarTheme"

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
[Activity(Label = "My App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/Theme.CustomActionBarTheme")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
```

...

You have misspelled your theme name (`CustomerActionBarTheme` instead of `CustomActionBarTheme`) and Theme style is declared without the `android:` prefix